# Error in seq.default(min(x), max(x), length = evaluation) : 'from' must be a finite number, when using scatterplotMatrix function

Tags: r, sequence, scatter-plot, infinity

I am trying to plot my data using `scatterplotMatrix`, to draw scatter plots depend on different ID.

Yet I got an error:

> seq.default(min(x), max(x), length = evaluation) : 'from' must be a finite number.

Here is my code

```
scatterplotMatrix(~ mean_f0_hz + max_f0_hz + min_f0_hz + range_f0_hz + q25_hz + q50_hz + q75_hz + sound_duration_s + am_var_d_b_s + am_rate_s_1 + am_extent_d_b + harmonicity + mean_wiener_entropy|id, data=df_squeal)
```

I explored my data, removing "na"s, removing "0"s, and removing levels in "id" that were less than 5. However, it is still not work. Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Are there any `-Inf`?

Comment: In my data, no. From the error, I guess so when drawing the plot. Yet I don't know how to check it....I went through the help file for scatterplotMatrix function, but found nothing help.

Comment: We can't offer much help without seeing your data. I would suggest running it with just a couple variables at a time to isolate which variable(s) produce the error. Then [edit] your post to include data from that variable, another variable that doesn't produce the error, and `id`. e.g. if `harmonicity` causes the error, provide the result of `dput(df_squeal[, c("id", "harmonicity", "mean_wiener_entropy")])`.